# how to identify all the numbers with decimals and keep two decimals but in the same time keep those ID numbers in the original ways？

Tags: r

I‘m dealing with a dirty dataframe，with different type of numeric numbers and ID numbers etc，in the dataframe it has 600+ lists，
**how to identify all the numbers with
decimals and keep two decimals but in the same time keep those ID numbers、numbers stand for gender in the original ways？**

Remember there are more lists in real data.

Thank you for your time and patience.

**data**

```
dirtydataset <- structure(list(ID = c("44052195405102041", "44052195405102042", "44052195405102043", 
                                    "44052195405102044", "440521954051020415", 
                                    "44052195405102046"), 
                           name = c("Angel", "Bob", "Cathy", "Dean", "Ellen",  "Faye"), 
                           gender = c("1", "2", "2", NA, "1", "2"), 
                           BIM = c(NA, "22.222", "18", NA, "21.2223", NA), 
                           eyen= c("7.2222", "1.01", NA, "2.3", NA, NA)), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
dirtydataset %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(BIM, eyen), ~round(.,2), .names = "rounded_{.col}"))
```

```
           ID  name gender     BIM   eyen rounded_BIM rounded_eyen
1 4.40522e+16 Angel      1      NA 7.2222          NA         7.22
2 4.40522e+16   Bob      2 22.2220 1.0100       22.22         1.01
3 4.40522e+16 Cathy      2 18.0000     NA       18.00           NA
4 4.40522e+16  Dean     NA      NA 2.3000          NA         2.30
5 4.40522e+17 Ellen      1 21.2223     NA       21.22           NA
6 4.40522e+16  Faye      2      NA     NA          NA           NA
```

Comment: the thing is it‘s not just two lists，except for“BIM”“eyen” ，there might be 60+